# How to retrieve the current background-image value of an element with IE6?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, dd-belatedpng

This is a bit maddening.  I have code which saves the current background-image from a selected element into a variable, which I then use to create an img tag.

Simply put, the following works in all browsers I've tested except IE6:

```
var bg = $('.element_selector').css('background-image');
```

The return value from IE6 is 'none', which is incorrect.  (Before anyone suggests trying 'backgroundImage' instead of 'background-image', no dice.)

Any ideas on how I can get that value?

**Update**: I forgot to mention that the background image in question was processed by [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/), which now appears to be the culprit -- if I comment out the fix, I get my value.  If anyone knows offhand how I could still fetch that value after the png fix is in, please let me know.

Comment: Can you put your code on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing in IE6 I was able to reproduce your issue with [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) and background src.

Here's what I've found.  If you set the `background-image` variable before calling `DD_belatedPNG.fix('[selector]');` then you get the desired result.  If you're setting it afterward for instance in a `click` event you get a value of `"none"`.

Additionally, DD_belatedPNG adds an image element to the page containing your background image (with a class of `DD_belatedPNG_sizeFinder`), so you can potentially 1) re-use, 2) copy, or 3) take `src` attribute value from that element.

Here's my testing code:

CSS:

```
#myElement
{
    width: 515px;
    height: 341px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #f00 url('http://www.chismbrothers.com/images/woodfloors.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>


<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<div id="test3"></div>
<div id="test4"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Works as expected
    var bg = $('#myElement').css('background-image');
    $('#test1').text("pre png fix: " + bg);

    DD_belatedPNG.fix('#myElement');

    $('#myElement').click(function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        var bgAll = $(this).css('background');

        // This yields values of 'none' for bg and 'undefined' for bgAll
        $('#test2').html("post png fix: " + bg + "<br />bg: " + bgAll);

        // DD_belatedPNG creates an image element on the page with a class of 
        // 'DD_belatedPNG_sizeFinder' which can be used to get the image src
        $('#test3').html('dd_belatedpng_sizeFinder: ' + $('.DD_belatedPNG_sizeFinder').attr("src"));

        // Perhaps reapplying 'zoom' css will reapply the BG values?
        $(this).css({ zoom: 0 }).css({ zoom: 1 });
        // Set values again.
        bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bgAll = $(this).css('background');
        // No luck...same result as #test2
         $('#test4').html("post png fix: " + bg + "<br />bg: " + bgAll);
    });
});
```

Comment: Moving the png fix to after the assignment caused a bit of heartburn, but it was the pragmatic solution (since I do a number of png fixes on that page).  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried `background`?
2. Are you sure the element is right?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  The proper value for background-image is returned in all other browsers I've tried (IE7-8, FF, misc webkit).   In IE6, css('background') returns undefined.

Comment: I think I just figured it out.  DD_belatedPNG appears to be the culprit, and I neglected to consider that it might be relevant.  Now to figure out where the png fix is hiding my data. :)